# How can I do a zend_db_table query with the criteria involving a dependent table?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, relationships

I have a table of events and a _dependentTable of eventPerformers. One event can have multiple performers. The performers are related to the events via eventId key within the eventPerformers table. The events table holds no performer data.

Using Zend_DB_Table classes, how can I pull back all events that have a specific performerId? sorting by a date field in the events table?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you read this - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by utilizing joins. For more information, and examples, you can have a look at the [Zend Framework db select manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html).

It's just a regular mysql query with `INNER JOIN` and `SORT BY event.date` (verify by echoing the Zend select() generated query)